# Simple Version of Gerstner Wave Formula?

Tags: wave-equation

I am attempting to implement these formulas into a wave simulator for java. But i am trouble understand a lot of parts of the equation:

http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch01.html

For example in equation 1:

It returns $Wi(x,y,t)$ as with all other equations there;
Whats weird to me is that its returning $t$ and not $z$?
And why is it returning values for $Wi()$, when in the equation it uses $Wi$ to calculate it:

$x Wi + t?$

Also is this returning a 2 dimensional Vector or a three-dimensional vector? 
For what im doing, i need a Vector3$f(x,y,z)$ to apply it to vertices in my grid mesh. But I'm rather confused.

Would it be possible for you to explain it to me in simple terms, or provide a link to a simplified version perhaps?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> Whats weird to me is that its returning t and not z?

The variables $x,y,t$ are not "returned", they are the arguments of function $W$. The third argument is named $t$ and not $z$, because it represents time, not the third spatial coordinate. The formulas are for wave in two spatial dimensions.

> And why is it returning values for Wi(), when in the equation it uses Wi to calculate it:

Mathematics is case-sensitive. The equation involves $w_i$, which is the angular frequency of the wave (mentioned in the first bullet point before the formula).

> Also is this returning a 2 dimensional Vector or a Three dimensional Vector?

The function $W_i$ returns a scalar, "the state of each wave as a function of horizontal position and time".